# Windsor TypedFactoryInterceptor Memory Leak

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, castle-windsor

I believe there is a memory leak with the TypedFactoryInterceptor.

Please consider the following scenario:

```
[Factory]
public interface IMyFactory 
{
     MySingleton GetInstance();
}

[Singleton]
public class MySingleton
{
}

[Singleton]
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(IMyFactory factory)
    {
        // using a for loop to simulate repeated calls to the factory instance over
        // a long time
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var instance = factory.GetInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, the TypedFactoryInterceptor will contain a list of 100000 WeakReferences, all of which point to the same Target instance (of MySingleton). So, in the scenario where one singleton depends of a factory to create instances of another singleton, you can end up with hundreds of thousands of WeakReferences and thus a memory leak.

In doing some looking at the source code, it looks like the problem is here (in TypedFactoryInterceptor.Resolve):

```
// this is called on every Resolve call to the TypedFactory (IMyFactory.GetInstance)
if (this.kernel.ReleasePolicy.HasTrack(instance))
{
    // there will not be any dead references because MySingleton is a Singleton
    this.CollectDeadReferences();
    // adds another WeakReference to the same Singleton instance
    this.resolvedTrackedComponents.Add(new WeakReference(instance));
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a result of the trick with `WeakReference`s being a workoaround for architectural limitations in Windsor 2.5 rather than a full blown solution.

This is fixed in (upcoming) Windsor 3, where no `WeakReference`s are involved.

As a temporary workaround I guess your best option is to not use a factory for that singleton (or upgrade to Windsor 3).

Comment: is there any source of information on Windsor 3? I can't seem to find any on google?

Comment: what sorts of information? It's still Windsor, you use it pretty much in the same way, the list of changes is in changelog, breaking changes are listed in breakingchanges.txt...

Comment: but I will need to build the source, right? there is no official beta release or anything?

Comment: I think the Master branch is version 3

Comment: beta comes out in less than 2 weeks. So it's quite stable. I'm running on master as I know few other people are with no issues so far.